Retrieving Value's from dictonaries
I recieve dictionaries in the following format.
data={'name'[{    'name1': value1, 'name2': value2, 'name3': value3, 'name4': value4, }{     'name1': value1, 'name2': value2, 'name3': value3, 'name4': value4, }{     'name1': value1, 'name2': value2, 'name3': value3, 'name4': value4}]}
How do I retrieve each say value3 string and store them each seperately in a file?
I haven't really tried much as I don't know what to do.

well not totally clear what you are trying to do,  your JSON if that what that is supposed to be,  is malformed.  and I wouldn't call that a dictionary. it is an object.
you did not tag any programming language and since it kind of looks like JSON I am going to guess JavaScript?
you really need to fix your question.
but assuming it is JavaScript you can use map to get name3 values.


const [value1, value2, value3, value4] = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];

let data = {
    'name': [
        {'name1': value1, 'name2': value2, 'name3': value3, 'name4': value4},
        {'name1': value1, 'name2': value2, 'name3': value3, 'name4': value4},
        {'name1': value1, 'name2': value2, 'name3': value3, 'name4': value4}
    ]
};

const result = data.name.map(x => x.name3);
console.log(result);



